# Como extrair um texto específico de uma string via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, html-tags, indexof

Dúvida relacionada a como retirar somente uma parte do texto que fica depois das minhas tags `p:` e `r:`

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação similar ao chatbot simsimi e por questões de teste estou armazenando as perguntas e respostas numa var dentro do script. Para que o bot possa aprender perguntas e respostas novas, estou tentando criar um comando onde o usuário mandaria a pergunta e a resposta através do uso das tags `p:` e `r:` como no exemplo abaixo:

**Exemplo**:

```
var text = "p: pergunta r: resposta"
```

Para isso eu teria que pegar somente o conteúdo dentro as minhas tags mas não sei como fazer isso. Via `.indexOf()` eu até tentei mas não sei como limitar o que ele pega até o começo da próxima tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes usar uma RegExp para extrair esses pares pergunta/resposta.

Poderia ser algo assim:

```js
var texto = "p: perguntaA r: respostaA p: perguntaB r: respostaB p: perguntaC r: respostaC";
var regex = /((\w:\s?)([^:]+)\s(\w:\s?)([^:]+)(\s|$))/g;
var pares = [], match;
while (match = regex.exec(texto)) {
    pares.push({
        p: match[3],
        r: match[5]
    });
}
console.log(pares);
```

Podes ver a regex em funcionamento aqui: https://regex101.com/r/I8yCcg/1 mas a ideia é:

- um "super grupo" de captura, com dois grupos iguais dentro
- `(\w:\s?)` refere-se a `p:` ou `r:`
- `([^:]+)` quer dizer "algo exceto `;`"
- e depois desse grupo `\s` ou `$` para garantir que há um espaço ou final de linha antes do proximo match.

Answer (score 0):

para a resposta

```
text.substr((text.search(/r:/)+2))
```

para a pergunta

```
text.substr((text.search(/p:/)+2),(text.search(/r:/)-2))
```

Comment: isso se for como no exemplo, se for em um cenário onde não sabe como vai chegar (com palavras antes do p:) o melhor é ir recortando a string

Comment: pra resolver isso eu criei um if onde só seria aceito se a ordem fosse p: e r: respectivamente, onde o p: teria que estar no começo da mensagem.

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo que use 2 inputs, um para a pergunta e outro para a resposta. Temos que sempre esperar que o usuário vai fazer da maneira errada, ou seja, não botar o "p:" e o "r:" da maneira correta, se colocar.

Crie 2 inputs e depois pegue o que foi digitado neles.
Aqui tem exemplos caso você queira usar JS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-how-to-get-value-of-text-input-field

E aqui usando JQuery:

```
var text= $('#input_name').val();
```

Comment: Sim, o problema é que a pergunta e a resposta seria envida no input onde são enviadas as mensagens